# Android step counter

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am trying to make a simple Android application to count steps. When I run the application the else is called in the onResume method meaning it did not find the sensor. I am testing on a 2016 Samsung J3 running Api 22. I am wondering is the problem in my code or is it that the phone does not have the sensor. If it is the phone is there a workaround for it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener
{

private TextView counterTextView;

private SensorManager sensorManager;

private boolean isWalking;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counterTextView = findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    isWalking = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if(countSensor != null)
    {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
    else
    {
        counterTextView.setText("WARNING SENSOR NOT FOUND");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    isWalking = false;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if(isWalking)
    {
        counterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
{

}
}
```

Comment: see device specification https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j3_(2016)-7760.php

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same situation as me, it was the device I was using. If you want to work with all devices you can use the accelerometer.