# Trying STEP_DETECTOR on a real Android device

Tags: android, sensors

I face the following problem:
in the onCreate method of an activity I want to get the reference to a STEP_DETECTOR

```java
 mStepCounter = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
```

in the OnResume method of my activity, I attach a sensorListener to that sensor

```java
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorStepsListener,mStepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

The *mSensorStepsListener* is defined at the beginning of the Activity:

```java
private SensorEventListener mSensorStepsListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


            mNombrePas ++;
            mCompteurPas.setText("nombre de pas realisés:" + String.valueOf(mNombrePas));
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            //Nothing to do
        }
    };
```

I do increment *mNombreDePas* (the number of steps) and update a textView on my layout witth that number!

But nothing happens on my Android device and while running in Debug mode I never reach the instructions in *onSensorChanged*

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure the device has this sensor? Check if `getDefaultSensor` really does return something (sensor exists on that device). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53958841/150978

Comment: getDefaultSensor does return a not null Sensor object. Do I have to declare this sensor in the Manifest ? I had not to declare the magnetic and the accelerometer in the Manifest ....

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments section. Edit your question instead and add the code there.

Comment: Please read and apply what I wrote in my last comment.